# Variable declaration via macro into inline function

Tags: c, inline, declaration, c-preprocessor

I have just a fast question. I use this macro to create new array:

```
#define NEW_ARRAY(id,size) int id[size]={0,}
```

Can I make a inline function that does same thing? (without malloc, I need swap between macros and inlines with conditional compilation without changing a source code)

I assume it isn't possible, however I want to ask you just in case there is a option.

Comment: Does it **need** to be a VLA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. In case of inline function you need to allocate memory on heap and then return a pointer to that allocated memory.